# Optimizing rasters and .mxd file to read them faster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, vector, cloud-optimized-geotiff

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 and have large raster and vector files on server which should be available for other PCs to see (they are viewing them in ArcReader).

So far, I compressed rasters in lossy compression, projected them, joined them with 'mosaic to new raster' and finally defragmented .mxd file.

Since others have much less RAMs than me, in which ways can I optimize files and .mxd even more?

*I read I could cloud optimize raster but I don't know how and if that'd help at all.

Comment: Have you built [overviews](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-overviews.htm) for the raster layers?

Comment: @BERA No, doing them right now, thanks! Will mark it as answered in the end.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.4 was retired 19 months ago. Lossy compression isn't likely to help hosts with low RAM, since this will actually *increase* RAM utilization (it needs to be decompressed somewhere). You likely have network access issues as well, for which a web-based GIS might be a better solution than ArcReader.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for advice regarding the compression. Unfortunately, customer is only using ArcReader. You think there is a way to connect ArcReader with web-based GIS or import the map in ArcReader through web or server without putting data in .pmf file?

Comment: pmf - file does not store GIS sources, it just points at them. I use base layers from servers all the time and ArcReader displays them nicely.

Answer (score 0):

- built overviews and pyramids helped the most

EDIT:
Both helped in the same way because I tried my rasters as new raster and new dataset of rasters. They helped because they render low and different resolutions of input raster on different scales.

Comment: Your answer is quite incomplete. Please explain how or why it helped.